# I am trying to run react project through yarn but it is giving me error what should i do now?

Tags: reactjs, npm, error-handling, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

i am trying to run react porject through YARN but it is giving error react-scripts.js already exists in file what should i do now 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2Txk.png)

Answer (score 0):

please run command- "npm install" ,it will install react-script dependency.